# Tool to write XPATH automatically for web parser?

Tags: xpath, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

Currently I need to extract data from websites.
I tried using HTML Agility Pack, which uses XPATH to extract data.
Is there a tool available which automates writing XPATH so that even a naive user can use the configure the parsing tool without writing XPATH.
Please provide your valuable suggestions for my scenarios.

NOTE:
Some tools are available for writing XPATH but it requires well formed XML but in my case I have malformed HTML documents as input.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is [such a tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl)!

You can certainly use the built in method present in many web browsers (as suggested by Mike). However, there are also additional plugins and utilities.

I've found the Chrome Extension [XPath Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl) to be the most useful. It serves the same purpose, but it is easy to use and creates more robust XPath expressions (based on attributes such as id) rather than just position. You can also edit the expression inline and see the results in real-time.

Comment: I explored it for some time and it was quite impressive.
Do you know any open source library which is available to achieve the same ?

Comment: No, I don't... but you can view the JS code for the extension by pressing F12 in Chrome and viewing `bar.js` in `Scripts`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what you're going for here, but when I use the HtmlAgilityPack, I leverage the Linq functionality way more than the XPath. My favorite tactic is using the Descendants method, particularly when adding a Where clause to narrow the search. From there, you can check the Name, Id, or use GetAttributeValue to check other attributes (like href). I find Linq far clearer to read and it lets me get quite elaborate with my parsing without getting lost in the XPath syntax.

Comment: The reason for moving towards XPATH is I am letting naive users captue HTML from automated tools so that he can still be completely ignorant of id, name. I dont want user to know bother about the complexity of the page. If in Linq I can achieve the same please advice.

Comment: You can. As I mention above, you can use GetAttributeValue on a node if you need to check for attributes and you can use InnerText or InnerHtml if you need to check for things inside the tags.

Comment: The main reason I parse because I dont know the innerText. In this scenario XPATH seems a bit reliable.

Comment: So don't use InnerText. Use GetAttributeValue. Or any of the other well-documented properties of HtmlNode. Or anything else you can think of to differentiate elements. It's LINQ. Build the query you want to. Or use XPath if you wish. Your question asks if there's a way to do it without XPath and there is.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the website in Chrome browser
2. Press Ctrl+Shift+I (Developer instruments will be opened)
3. Select "Elements" at the top of instrument window
4. Select magnifying glass at the bottom of instrument window
5. Select the desired element in the browser
6. Right-click selected row in the DOM-tree and choose "Copy XPath"

Comment: I am not getting copy xpath option. I am getting options like add attibute, edit attribute,edit as HTMl, copy as HTML,Delete node,break on subtree modification, break on attributes modification, break on node removal, Inspect element